# Add a trigger on select

Tags: sql, mariadb

Is it possible to create a select trigger? I know there are update insert or delete triggers. But select trigger is what I need for a little url shortener application. Everytime a shorturl is hit I'd like to update counter and last access date. A select trigger would be perfect.

```
select url where code = :code
```

whould be the one to trigger the trigger.

Comment: No. But maybe there's something else that can be done.  Please add some detail (a complete test case) indicating exactly what you want done.  Where is the URL?  Where is the short URL?  Where is the counter?  Where is the last access date?  Show the schema / tables.  What does it mean to "hit a short URL"?

Comment: Thanks @JonArmstrong that was particularly unclear to begin with. What I wanted is a successfull search in a table being logged as such (doing a ulr relay/shortening project). My solution is in a stored function that updates the table and returns the result.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing this:

```
create function `get_the_url`(c char(7))
returns varchar(255)
begin
    declare result varchar(255);
    update code
        set
            hits = hits + 1,
            last_used=current_timestamp()
        where code = c;
    return (
        select url
        from code
        where code = c
    );
end
```

saving this for prosperity and me.

for this table:

```
create table `code` (
  `code` char(5) not null,
  `url` varchar(240) default null,
  `last_used` datetime not null default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `hits` int(10) unsigned not null default 0,
  primary key (`code`) using hash,
  key `url` (`url`) using hash
) engine=myisam
```

For those few php folks interested, this is how I populated the table:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

$charset ="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNAOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890-_.!~*'()";
$size = 8;

function getCode(): string {
  global $size;
  global $charset;
  $length = strlen($charset)-1;

  $result =
   $charset[rand(0,$length)]
  .$charset[rand(0,$length)]
  .$charset[rand(0,$length)]
  .$charset[rand(0,$length)]
  .$charset[rand(0,$length)];
  return $result;
}


$db = new \PDO("mysql:dbname=qr","qr","qr");
$insert = $db-> prepare("insert into code(code,url,last_used,hits)values(:code,null,default,default)");
$code = getCode();
$insert->bindParam(':code',$code);

for($i=1000; $i>0; $i--) {
  $code = getCode();
  $insert-> execute() or die($insert->errorInfo()[2]);
}
```

and yes, populating this upfront probably makes sense as storage space is cheap and computing power is not.

Comment: `select qr.get_the_url('aV2vMEQ');` will return a url and update the fields. As long as the code is in the table.

Comment: https://twitter.com/billkarwin/status/1007376549740404736

Comment: :-) Yes @BillKarwin I guess it is that. When will the sql people behave?

Comment: And I was able to coerce MySQLWorkbench to temper its tone.